# Is my way of using MongoDB C# driver FindAsync flawed?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver, using-statement

Still kind of new to C#. My code gives me the results I want, but I'm uncertain if I did implemented it in an OK way. Please elaborate if you feel like answering.
My goal was to search for entries in my MongoDB via `FindAsync`. Here is my code for that:

```
public async Task<List<T>> SearchDocAsync<T, U>(string collection,
    string findFieldName, U findValue)
{
    var _collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collection);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(findFieldName, findValue);
    var result = await (_collection.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToListAsync());
    return result;
}
```

And here is the way I call it in WinForms:

```
private async void BtnReadAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var asyncResults = await myMongoAux.SearchDocAsync<MyTModel, string>(
        myCollectionName, "MyDBString", "TestString");
    foreach (var r in asyncResults)
    {
        RtxbxResult.Text += $"{r.MyDBInt}\t{r.MyDBString}\n";
    }
}
```

Is this safe? Shouldn't I be using a `using` (but how)? And I have read something about that you should use:

> ConfigureAwait(false)

How and why?

Be so kind and help me out understand more. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: How would a better SearchDocAsync-Methode look like? Any examples Links ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this looks odd

```
var result = await (_collection.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToListAsync());
```

It should probably be

```
var result = await ((await _collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToListAsync());
```

Using `.Result` for tasks will block until the task has completed. Due to the way threads work in UI applications this has a rather high chance of causing a deadlock. So it is recommended to avoid `.Result` and `.Wait()` unless you are sure that no deadlock can occur.

Comment: return await _collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync(); Is this then the correct  way to use find in an async-way?

Comment: @nogood I'm not familiar with MongoDb, but that looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on that method because you need to be back to the captured synchronization context (UI thread) after the `await`.

[ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)